# SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Part Context Ribbon Bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, ribbon

All,  I am having problems trying to find a good solution that I can create a ribbon bar based on my visual web part.  In my visual web part i have an RSS feed, and an Alert Me button, but the URL will need to be generated based on a dynamic URL.

Please assist.

Comment: Bill, Stackoverflow is about programming related questions. You question is more suited for sharepoint.stackexchange.com. Also you will need to provide a lot more information you cannot "create a ribbon bar based on your web part" the ribbon is a totally different concept. Did you read the "Customizing and Extending the SharePoint 2010 Server Ribbon" article from MS? If not, do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution.
http://spribbon.codeplex.com/